# Adobe Flex, what is this language similar to?

Tags: apache-flex

I recently heard about Adobe Flex. I am not sure what this programming language is. How can I use it in web development? For example, gilt taste by google uses HTML5, CSS3, and Adobe Flex. Forgive my ignorance, I only heard about this language yesterday.

Comment: I voted to close; as this is not a programming question and @wieuyr could have spent 5 minutes with Google to answer his question.

Comment: Question - "gilt taste by google uses HTML5, CSS3, and Adobe Flex"-- not sure what you're mentioning here, is there a typo?

Comment: Why close? Who cares...it's close enough to a programming question, and it's commonly asked by anyone new to Flex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flex is a framework for flash. You can use the following languages in the Flex framework:

- [MXML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MXML)
- [Actionscript 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript#ActionScript_3.0)
- Css

Flex was created for making flash applications easier and faster since you can do a lot of things without being forced to use Actionscript 3.

For example, if you wanted to set the color of the border of a textfield, add the text "hello" and add it to the stage. This is how you would do it in Flash using Actionscript 3:

```
var yourTextfield:TextField = new TextField();
yourTextfield..border.fill.color.value = 0xff3300;
yourTextfield.text = "hello";
addChild(yourTextfield);
```

And here's how you do it in the Flex framework using MXML:

```
<s:TextArea text="hello" borderColor="#ff3300"/>
```

Comment: Well now you know :) I added some proof of concept code for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Ancide's answer covers the basics.  But to answer the question a bit more **("similar to")**, ActionScript is often compared to Java for it's similarities. (Although there are a few differences. IMO AS3 has some nice feature improvements over Java such as implicit getters/setters, a more flexible switch() statement, simple 'Function pointers'--for lack of a better term, functions can be easily passed as parameters--useful for implementing event handlers, and so on.)

MXML is similar to Microsoft WPF/Silverlight's XAML and is generally used for similar purposes.